# c# Открыть векторный файл (svg) и нарисовать его в PictureBox

Tags: c#, svg, picturebox

У меня есть файл .SVG формата. Свойство Image у PictureBox не принимает такой формат на вход. Как можно добавить это изображение?

p.s. пробовал реализовать через метод, который возвращал-бы bitmap (картинку загрузил в ресурсы проекта), но выдаёт ошибку (System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The specified document cannot be found."). Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что я не совсем правильно загрузил этот файл в ресурсы

```
    private Bitmap ConvertToBitmnap()
    {
        var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(Properties.Resources.image.ToString());
        svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto;
        return svgDocument.Draw(12, 12);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот SvgDocument из какой библиотеки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `SvgDocument.Open()` принимает [значение `string`](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgDocument.cs#L311) соответствующее именно файлу .svg, [или stream](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgDocument.cs#L358) содержащий сам код SVG.

В вашем случае, вы вызываете первый overload, и даёте ему значение `"System.Byte[]"`. Так как файла с именем «System.Byte[]» не существует, то программа логично указывает, что файла нет.

Используйте [`GetManifestResourceStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetManifestResourceStream_System_String_). Загрузите картинку из ресурсов, и дальше используйте стрим, вызывая `SvgDocument.Open()`.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что нужно в метод Open вписать что-то такое `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Properties.Resources.image)`? Просто, мне он не даёт даже скомпилировать проект

Comment: Такой вариант тоже не работает `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("image.svg")`

Comment: Вот [пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/240613), где используется GetManifestResourceStream. А что говорит ошибка при компилировании?

Comment: `Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.IO.Stream" в "string"`. Я находил эту статью, но там для работы с txt файлом, а у меня картинка. Или разницы нет?

Comment: Хм, так у вас уже значит stream имеется, вот как удачно. Тогда просто этот стрим давайте методу SvgDocument.Open, а GetManifestResourceStream значит не нужен.

Comment: Мне кажется, я вас не очень понимаю. В данный момент, в такое происходит https://pastenow.ru/DLDY7

Comment: @Frehzy: Простите, что так непонятно объясняю. Когда вы написали `GetManifestResourceStream(Properties.Resources.image)`, то компилятор начал ругаться, говоря, что `Properties.Resources.image`, это стрим. Поэтому можете убрать вызов GetManifestResourceStream, и делать напрямик вот так: `var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(Properties.Resources.image);`